# Nginx server with PHP FDM for Apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx, plesk

I'm wondering if using a PHP FDM served by Apache, with some other server settings under Nginx, could cause any problem.
Because I'm experiencing some issues executing scripts (the site goes 504 a lot).
I'm on Plesk Onix, Proxy mode ON, PHP FDM served by Apache.
Will I gain something turning Proxy Mode off and switching PHP to FDM served by Nginx?

Thank you a lot

Comment: It is highly unlikely that your setup uses both apache and nginx with FPM so nginx settings do not apply in "FPM application served by Apache" mode (and vise versa). Right now apache (as an proxy) does not wait long enough for the FPM to complete its task. There could be multiple reasons for this: either your php code is slow or you have high load but do not have enough fpm workers configured. You did not provide enough information for people to help you. Does it timeout at some specific request or on all pages? How many requests (per second or minute) does your server get?